# MarkerClusterGroup - I want to show most important information first when user zooms

Tags: leaflet

Let's say that I use MarkerClusterGroup and have markers for cities and I know their population. When I zoom I want to first show the cities with most population. Because now it seems that cluster are visible only if they cannot to belong to any cluster. Can I set priorities what markers to show first?

Is it possible to achieve that in LeafetJS?

I read about SubGroup but I don't know if its useful.